# why wont validate fire the error - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Why won't validate fire the error as "fred"  should make the validate condition return true when it is set?

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('inisialize Person');
        this.bind("change:name", function () {
            console.log(this.get('name') + ' is now the name value')

        });
        this.bind("error", function (model, error) {

            console.log(error);

        });
    },
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        height: ''
    },
    validate: function (attributes, options) {  

        if (attributes.name == "fred") { //why wont this work?

            return "oh no fred is not allowed";
        }

    }

});

//var person = new Person({ name: 'joe', height: '6 feet' });
var person = new Person();
person.set({ name: 'fred', height: '200' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validate() is called when saving, but not when setting an attribute unless you explicitly tell it to do so. From the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

> By default validate is called before save, but can also be called
>   before set if {validate:true} is passed.

Comment: thanks   -  looks like i need to add person.set({ name: 'fred', height: '200' },{validate:true});

Comment: and   error must be changed to invalid this.bind("invalid", function (model, error) {

            console.log(error);

        });

Comment: @Hello-World Right. In the doc example he listens for the "invalid" state on the instance of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In the `initialize()`, change the `this.bind('error')` to `this.on('invalid')` The `'error'` event is for failures at the server, after when calling save(). The `'invalid'` is for validation errors on the client side. Lastly, add `{validate: true}` as a second argument to the `person.set()` calls. Backbone doesn't validate `set()` by default.

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        height: ''
    }, 

    validate: function(attributes) {
      if(attributes.name === 'fred' )
        return 'oh no fred is not allowed';
    },

    initialize: function() {
        alert('welcome');
        this.on('invalid', function(model, error){
          alert(error);
        });
        //listeners
        this.on('change:name', function(model) {
            var name = model.get('name');
            alert('changed ' + name);
        });

});

var person = new Person();
person.set({ name: 'fred', height: '200' }, {validate: true}); //oh no fred is not allowed
```